# Link Column's color in a chart to a range in the worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have a range next to data area of the column-chart. I have to relate each column's color of the chart with this range. E.g. if there is "X" in the table, so the chart-column ralated to this row would be red, else green.

I have written something like this here below, but it doesn't work. On the other hand VBA doesn't discard this code :)

Data column begins in E2 and chart's columns are Point(1), ...(2) etc.

```
Sub Chart_Color()

Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate 'sheet's name
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select

LineNum = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count
For i = 1 To LineNum
i = i + 1
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E:E").Cells(i + 1).Value = "X" Then
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Select
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
Else
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: When you say 'it doesn't work', what is it that it doesn't do? Also, a snapshot of the worksheet would help to understand the issue

Comment: I gess it doesn't understand, wich cell relates to wich column. Procedure changes the colors sometimes randomly.

Comment: It works if I write manualy Dim Point1 As Range
Set Point1 = Range("E2")

Comment: As I don't have your worksheet, I cannot test your code and make recommendations but I can help with some of the logic in your code.. 1. Always qualify your worksheet: `Dim oW As Worksheet: Set oW = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`. 2. The way you assign the value to `LineNum` is very volatile. Try something like this: `LineNum = oW.Cells(oW.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`. 3. You are incrementing 'i' within your `FOR` loop, I suspect you don't need that. 4. Remove `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Select` line outside the `IF` because this is not dependent on your condition

Comment: Now without `For`  it works, but only for first column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the presumption that your above code works, which I can't test (in part because I don't have Office 365), the code below should work more efficiently.

```
Dim ColorId As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim R As Long                           ' row number
Dim i As Long


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    For R = 2 To LastRow                ' start in row 2
        ColorId = InStr(1, "XYZ", Trim(.Cells(R, "E").Value), vbTextCompare)
        If ColorId Then
            ColorId = Array(vbRed, vbGreen, vbBlue)(ColorId - 1)
            With Worksheets("Ma").ChartObjects("Chart 1").FullSeriesCollection(R - 1)
                For i = 1 To .Points.Count
                    .Points(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor = ColorId
                Next i
            End With
        End If
    Next R
End With
```

In case it doesn't work you might like to lift the loop construction from it. Your loop includes many thousands of cells which aren't required. The other thing I urge you to consider is my attempt to do without activating or selecting anything. I know it is possible, I know that doing so is better, but I might not quite have found the correct syntax to address the FullSeriesCollection. This I have borrowed and transscribed from your own code.

If vbRed, vbGreen and vbBlue doesn't work for you the following code can replace these values. Place it at the top of the above code, just under `Dim R As Long`, except for the last line which must replace the similar line of code in the middle of the procedure.

```
Dim myRed As Long, myGreen As Long, myBlue As Long

myRed = RGB(0, 0, 255)
myGreen = RGB(255, 255, 0)
myBlue = RGB(0, 255, 0)
Set ColorId = Array(myRed, myGreen, myBlue)(ColorId - 1)
```

Comment: Looks interesting, but "type mismatch": `ColorId = InStr("X", Trim(.Cells(R, "E").Value), vbTextCompare)`

Comment: Syntax error in my code. Sorry about that. The Instr() function needs a start byte if vbTextCompare is specified. I have added that in the code above. Now it's `ColorId = InStr(1, "XYZ", Trim(.Cells(R, "E").Value), vbTextCompare)`. The point of using vbTextCompare is to enable "x" (lower case) to be found in "XYZ" (all caps).

Comment: Now it gives an "object or metode error", I guess because "i" in `Point(i)` doesn't have any definition. Any case, it accepts neither "R" nor "1". Nonetheless, those columns and cells must have the same variable, in this case may be R and R-1, but something is wrong.

Comment: But if there isn't any X,Y or Z in the table, VBA doesn't give any error.

Comment: It's programmed not to throw an error. The line `If ColorId Then` does that in conjunction with the Instr() function. The FullSerieesCollection.Points(i) is the part I can't get at. That's why I didn't program for the i variable at all. Now I have changed the posted answer to include setting of 100 points. I have no idea if that is correct. Just guessing. `R` is a row number and has nothing to do with the chart.

Comment: The same error in `Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart1").FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor = ColorId`. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Now it works :)

```
Sub chart_color()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Cell As Range
Dim i As Byte

For i = 0 To 100
For Each Cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Offset(i, 0)

If Cell.Value = "X" Then
Worksheets("Ma").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
End If
If Cell.Value = "Y" Then
Worksheets("Ma").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If
If Cell.Value = "Z" Then
Worksheets("Ma").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
End If

Next Cell
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

We are now looking at this portion of my code which you find that it doesn't work (sorry, I can't test).

```
ColorId = vbRed            ' ColorId is a Long
i = 1
Worksheets("Ma").ChartObjects("Chart 1").FullSeriesCollection(1) _
                            .Points(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor = ColorId
```

This is supposed to be the equivalent of your code of which you say that it does work.

```
i = 1
Worksheets("Ma").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
```

Let's forget about the value of i for the moment. The value of 1 which I assign to it is arbitrary.

I tested both `.Fill.ForeColor = ColorId` and `.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ColorId` on a shape object and they both work. Therefore it should be possible to simply replace my 1 1/2 lines of code with your two lines of code and replace `RGB(255, 255, 0)' with 'ColorId'. You may also have to activate (Select) Worksheets("Ma") before you can activate a chart in it.

I studied both the SeriesCollection and Points methods and will therefore amend my above code to improve the referencing of both which may open new sources of error. Are you sure you need to format the points? My instinct is to try and set the colour like this:-

```
Worksheets("Ma").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1) _
                .Interior.Color = ColorId
```

Replace `SeriesCollection` with `FullSeriesCollection` only if you do filtering.

Comment: At least has a recording shown, that `SeriesCollection` or `FullSeriesCollection`are an area on the chart and `Point` is one column of this collection.

Comment: I have make a couple of changes and added the code to your post. In this mode it works.

Comment: Also I can't undersand why, but if I write the address of the chart in one line I get an error message, but in two lines it works perfectly.

Comment: Did you try adding the `.RGB` into my code? Like, `.Points(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ColorId`

Comment: Yes. And I have deleted "i" at all and replaced by "R-1". Thanks for your help!